# I have created a form with a list inside of it, and I am trying to access that list in a new form

Tags: c#

I am working on an assignment, where I need to have the user input the name and time of a competitor in a race. Once they input the form, they can go to a "View" screen (which is my new form) which will allow them to view the times.

Each race has 6 categories, so I created 6 lists in the main form (with the input). These lists are created based on an object called Competitor (which requires the name and time)

Now I need to take that list, and sort it in the "View" screen.
I am having trouble with this (I am very inexperienced with C#)

I tried referencing the input form, but to no avail. I know I am doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is.

```
public List<RaceCompute.Competitor> egg_adult_list = new List<RaceCompute.Competitor>();
public List<RaceCompute.Competitor> egg_teen_list = new List<RaceCompute.Competitor>();
public List<RaceCompute.Competitor> egg_kids_list = new List<RaceCompute.Competitor>();
public List<RaceCompute.Competitor> sack_adult_list = new List<RaceCompute.Competitor>();
public List<RaceCompute.Competitor> sack_teen_list = new List<RaceCompute.Competitor>();
public List<RaceCompute.Competitor> sack_kids_list = new List<RaceCompute.Competitor>();

public input_form()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public class RaceCompute
{
    public class Competitor
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Time { get; set; }

        public Competitor(string name, double time)
        {
            Name = name;
            Time = time;
        }
    }
}


// VIEW FORM //
input_form test2 = new input_form();
```

EDIT: Thanks a lot to the quick reply. I set the lists to public static and I can now access those lists. Again, I am very inexperienced but thanks for the help

Comment: Why do you need to have 6 lists? Is it not possible to have a third property on the Competitor class that keeps the competitor's kind? Or if there is more than just a type to differentiate the element, build a proper inheritance chain?

Comment: You can define the list as a `public static` property in the first form and then in the second form, create a new object of the first one and access the list like`FirstForm::list`.

Comment: A form is responsible for interacting with the user. Persisting lists of competitors is a separate responsibility, so it belongs in a separate class. Then both forms could reference that class.

Answer (score 0):

The code will not look pretty at the end however you can sort the List using Where or FirstOrDefault.

```
egg_kids_list.FirstOrDefault(i=> i.Name = NameToSearchFor);
```

Either do this 6 times for all your lists and then add all the result Competitor objects into another List and pass it in to your new form as a parameter.

```
DisplayList.Add(egg_kids_list_item_returned_by_filter);
```

Or a better option might be passing your first Form as a parameter to your 
second form

```
private class display_class
{
public display_class(data_class data)
{
     //Here you can already access your lists
     public List<RaceCompute.Competitor> egg_adult_list = data.egg_adult_list;
}
}
```